# How can we resuse https connections in ANT?

Tags: http, ant, https, get

I have a HTTPS GET task in ANT which downloads files off my server. Problem is I have to spawn a new HTTPS connection every time I have to download a single file.

I have quite a few files which need to be downloaded so naturally recreating new HTTP connections causes some grief.

Is there a way in ANT to reuse a HTTPS/HTTP connection so that I can download all my files over the same reuseable connection?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. Either write your own "get" task or consider other alternatives like [scp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html).

## Update

Off the top of my head I'm thinking that a custom task could accept an ANT fileset and then use an HTTP connection pool to fetch the files in parallel.

The key question is how much will this actually help. Have you measured the extra latency caused by this problem?

Perhaps instead of trying to optimize the HTTP connections, it might be simpler to just fetch the files in parallel? The following code uses 4 threads:

```
<target name="fetch">
    <parallel threadCount="4">
      <get dest="file1.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file2.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file3.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file4.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file5.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file6.jar" src="https://..."/>
      <get dest="file7.jar" src="https://..."/>
      ..
      ..
    </parallel>
</target>
```

Comment: Using scp isnt an option. GET is perhaps the only way, could you clarify on what the custom GET task would look like?